# ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defiened, phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, filesystems

Essential parts of index.html looks like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>

function init() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
} 
function onDeviceReady() {
//what do we have in cache already?
$("#status").html("Checking your local cache");    
    try {
    alert("start");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onError);  
    } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}
$("#status").html("After checking local");          
}

function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
    $("#status").html("Before get directory"); 
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Android/data/com.test.Testname",    {create:true},gotDir,onError);
    $("#status").html("After get directory");    
}
```

It goes through the try catch and throws me the ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined. I am testing this on my phone, and have tried other phones too with sdcard. 
These permissions added in AndroidManifest and I think other parts in the Manifest is ok:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Seen some other posts around here with same problem but no fix for me. Anyone?

Comment: The permissions block you posted is incomplete - I'm assuming they're `<uses-permission />` elements as opposed to `<permission />` elements?

Comment: @Squonk thats right, got an error when trying to make the question when starting with "<", so leaved out <uses-permission android:name=". Sorry about not making that clear :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

write this in manifest file . you might be doing wrong there.